# how do I figure out provisional throughput for AWS DynamoDB table?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throughput

My system is supposed to write a large amount of data into a DynamoDB table every day. These writes come in bursts, i.e. at certain times each day several different processes have to dump their output data into the same table. Speed of writing is not critical as long as all the daily data gets written before the next dump occurs. I need to figure out the right way of calculating the provisional capacity for my table.

So for simplicity let's assume that I have only one process writing data once a day and it has to write upto `X` items into the table (each item < 1KB). Is the capacity I would have to specify essentially equal to `X / 24 / 3600` writes/second?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provisioned capacity is in terms of writes/second. You need to make sure that you can handle the PEAK number of writes/second that you are going to expect, not the average over the day.  So, if you have a single process that runs once a day and makes X number of writes, of Y size (in KB, rounded up), over Z number of seconds, your formula would be

```
capacity = (X * Y) / Z
```

So, say you had 100K writes over 100 seconds and each write < 1KB, you would need 1000 w/s capacity.

Note that in order to minimize provisioned write capacity needs, it is best to add data into the system on a more continuous basis, so as to reduce peaks in necessary read/write capacity.

Comment: Thanks. Can I somehow ensure that I never go over the provisioned capacity? In other words, instead of relying on AWS to throttle my writes, do libraries like `boto` have the ability to control that from my side? If I have to slow down my writes to stay below that it's OK as long as I my writes end before the next dump. In this case I can use my formula I think. I definitely do not

Comment: I am not familiar with boto to know what it's capabilities are for throttling requests.  You should obviously have error handling mechanisms in your code which updates the database to look for errors being returned from dynamoDB, so that you can determine when such capacity problems are happening and perhaps throttle your code yourself, and retry any failed writes/reads. You can also use Cloudwatch to monitor your capacity usage to get a feel for when you might need to adjust capacity limits.

Comment: All of the official SDKs (including boto — the AWS SDK for Python) rely on the service to do the throttling. The SDKs simply respond to the throttling exception using an exponential back-off algorithm.